# Typescript creating modules

Tags: typescript, angular

I wanted to create modules for our library, so each time we call, we can use `import {Api, Map} from "ourlibrary"`

currently I'm using following.

```
import {Api} from "../../Library/Api";
import {MapPage} from "../map/map";
```

How I can create my own packages to get following result?

```
import {Api, Map} from "OurLib"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two steps to do that:

- Create an entry in the `map` block of your SystemJS configuration:

  ```
  System.config({
    map: {
      'OurLib': 'path-to-ourlib'
    },
    packages: {
      'OurLib': {
        main: 'index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
  ```
- Create a TypeScript file (for example, `index.ts`) as entry point module that import / export what you want to make available outside your library:

  ```
  export {Api} from "../../Library/Api";
  export {MapPage} from "../map/map";
  ```

Comment: I'm using ionic, which has tscnofig.json... how can I use settings on tsconfig? http://pastie.org/10752352 - it also have webdev.. kind of not sure if this goes on webdev or tsconfig

Comment: You mean that you want to define a contract for your lib, i.e. a ourlib.d.ts?

Answer (score 2):

Create a top-level ES6 style js file that exports your imports as a single file and name it `OurLib`.

```
exports.Api = require('../../Library/Api').Api;
exports.Map = require('.../map/map').Map;
```

The benefit of this approach is that it doesn't tie you to a single module loader system.  Since it is straight-forward ES6 features (require/export), it can be consumed by SystemJS, Webpack, Typescript etc.

As mentioned in the comment below, the reason for `.Api` and `.Map` at the end of the require statement is because what you are typically importing from your files are classes.  You would use syntax like this in the case of

```
export class Api {}
```

and

```
export class Map {}
```

in each of the respective files.  This way you only assign the classes that you WANT to export rather than the entire required file.  It gives you more control over your bundled, exposed module.

Comment: why to use `.Api` & `.map` at the end of line ?

Comment: You would typically be referencing a specific class within that imported file.

Comment: you mean `.Api and .map`  is the name of exported class ?

Comment: @Basit The global "namespace" would be defined by the file name "OurFile".  And you CAN export all, however, that would prevent you from any renaming/remapping that you would want to do and it would literally export all, which you might not want to do.

Comment: @Basit what does your index.d.ts file look like?  is anything actually being exported in it?

Comment: Yes, I found the solution, it was webpack resolve section fixed it, But thanks for looking into this.

Comment: `webpack` resolve works fine. the only issue I have now. import classes model editor.. like if I use `{Api}`, it will import it fine, but does not show what methods belongs to `Api` library in phpstorm like it does for angular2 library, do you know what I can do to fix that also. so `type hint` can also work