# Ionic2 Angular2 Typescript module - Type Hint issue

Tags: node.js, module, typescript, angular, ionic2

Coming from previous question [Typescript creating modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35872228/typescript-creating-modules).

I have created module outside `node_modules` folder and `phpstorm` does not pickup where is the library.

It does compile and does run fine, but type hint does not pickup, which causes issues when developing.

[image: type-hint]

If I put my module inside `node_modules`, then it picks up automatically, else it shows error as above.

How can I tell type hint of phpstorm where is my module outside `node_modules`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see where your `from` part is on that line, but I'm guessing since this works when everything is in *node_modules* that you must have forgot the `./` part.

**Import** looks in *node_modules* when your from looks like this:

```
 import * from 'something_in_node_modules';
```

If you add `./` **in front** of the file location, it will look in the current directory you're in.

For example:

```
 import * from './some-ts-file-in-this-directory';
```

Try that, and it should fix the problem!

Comment: How can I use `import * from 'something_in_note_modules_OR_another_folder`?

Comment: If you're using weback you could do some conditionals in the import. Why not import both?

Comment: Or do you mean `import { Something, Another } from 'somenodemodule';`

Comment: I mean import libraries from two different location one is node_module folder and another some other folder.  how can I add another folder on webpack.. following is my file http://pastie.org/10760617